# Как из таблицы MS SQL вытащить документ MS Word?

Tags: sql-server, ms-word

В базе данных MSSQL хранятся Аукционы и у каждого аукциона есть прикрепленный MS Word документ.
Вот мой скрипт с запросом.

```
DECLARE @Comm as varchar(400)


DECLARE Business CURSOR FOR

SELECT v.ID,p.document_id, p.pageno, p.extensions
FROM docum.dbo.Document v join docum.dbo.v_docpage_wr p on (p.document_id = v.ID)
where p.kind != '1' and v.Datefrom >= '2015.01.01' and v.Datefrom <= '2015.01.31'
ORDER BY v.ID, p.document_id, p.pageno, p.extensions

OPEN Business
FETCH NEXT FROM Business
INTO @ID, @Docum,@PageNo,@Extension

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN


SET @Comm = 'bcp "SELECT cast ([body] as ...)  FROM [docum].[dbo].[v_docpage_wr] WHERE [ID] =  ''' +cast(@ID  as nvarchar(50))+ '''"  queryout "C:\Auction\' + cast(@Docum as nvarchar(50)) + '-'  + cast(@PageNo as nvarchar(20)) + '.' + cast(@Extension as nvarchar(20)) +'" -T  '

 PRINT @Comm

EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE

  EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell @Comm
    FETCH NEXT FROM Business
    INTO @ID, @Docum,@PageNo,@Extension

END

CLOSE Business
DEALLOCATE Business
```

Какой формат данных нужно указать в функции cast()?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: @AnnaNazz, на будущее, [mysql](https://www.mysql.com/) — это совсем другая СУБД.

Comment: так все таки, как мне достать документы?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexejs/2009/06/06/573/